# Divide String Parameter Into Different Lines in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a perl line which is very long and I want to divide it into two lines for readability purposes.

Such as

```
system("SomeUnixCommand paremeter1 parameter2 ... parameterN");
```

Can I do something like this in Perl?

```
system("SomeUnixCommand paremeter1 parameter2 parameterK"
       "parameterK+1 ... parameterN");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to concatenate the quoted strings:

```
system("SomeUnixCommand paremeter1 parameter2 parameterK " .
       "parameterK+1 ... parameterN");
```

Answer (score 5):

If I've a lot of parameters to feed, I usually do it something like this:

```
my @params = qw ( param1 param2 param3 
                  anotherparam more_param 
                  param4 ... param999 );

system ( $command, @params);
```

(since system can take an array). For a more general case - `join ( " ", @params );`

`qw` is perl's "quote words" - it white-space separates array elements, so they stay readable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm upvoting this but I will choose dot answer because it is simpler to use in my case.

Comment: Caveat: `system()` with one argument can behave differently from `system()` with multiple arguments (regarding whether the shell is used or not). See [perldoc system](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html)